# Apache, Centos and Passenger SIGSEGV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

I have successfully installed Passenger on my CENTOS 6.6 i686 VPS with Rails 4.1.7 and Ruby 1.9.3

Pages are rendered successfully, however some CSS and JS files are rendered incomplete (they are complete in the fs).

I checked the logs and it seems that Passenger stops working sometime during the serving process.

The log is the following:

```
[ pid=28109, timestamp=1415060090 ] Process aborted! signo=SIGSEGV(11), 
reason=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x8, randomSeed=1415060076
[ pid=28109 ] Crash log dumped to /var/tmp/passenger-crash-log.1415060090
[ pid=28109 ] Date, uname and ulimits:
Tue Nov  4 02:14:50 EET 2014

Linux 2.6.32-042stab093.4 #1 SMP Mon Aug 11 18:47:39 MSK 2014 i686 i686
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 257105
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 16384
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 257105
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
[ pid=28109 ] Phusion Passenger version: 4.0.53
[ pid=28109 ] libc backtrace available!
```

Could it be a memory issue or something? The VPS is running on 1.5Gb RAM